# How could i know open transaction using sql query?

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I am using JDBC API for transaction..

This is my curiosity to know that if i am opening a transaction using JDBC API. Is there any entry in Oracle Database.

I am just looking for a query which show the result of open transaction when the transaction is opened by Application.

From the answer:

Google it for more information

Found a good article on same :

http://oraclue.com/2009/10/20/uncommitted-transaction/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a view - v$transaction, here is a [link to the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/dynviews_2149.htm).

Answer (score 5):

you can see open transactions by querying `gv$transaction` and `gv$session`. for example:

```
select s.inst_id, s.sid, s.serial#, s.username,
       s.program, s.osuser, s.status session_status,
       s.sql_id, t.status tran_status, 
       t.start_time tran_start, t.used_ublk used_undo_blocks, 
       t.used_urec used_undo_recs
  from gv$session s, gv$transaction t
 where t.addr = s.taddr;
```